# Creating a pygtk text field that only accepts number

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

Does anybody know how to create a text field using PyGTK that only accepts number. I am using Glade to build my UI.

Cheers,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't know about a way to do something like this by simple switching a settings, I guess you will need to handle this via signals, one way would be to connect to the `changed` signal and then filter out anything that's not a number.

Simple approach(untested but should work):

```
class NumberEntry(gtk.Entry):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Entry.__init__(self)
        self.connect('changed', self.on_changed)

    def on_changed(self, *args):
        text = self.get_text().strip()
        self.set_text(''.join([i for i in text if i in '0123456789']))
```

If you want formatted Numbers you could of course go more fancy with a regex or something else, to determine which characters should stay inside the entry.

**EDIT**
Since you may not want to create your Entry in Python I'm going to show you a simple way to "numbify" an existing one.

```
    def numbify(widget):
        def filter_numbers(entry, *args):
            text = entry.get_text().strip()
            entry.set_text(''.join([i for i in text if i in '0123456789']))

        widget.connect('changed', filter_numbers)

    # Use gtk.Builder rather than glade, you'll need to change the format of your .glade file in Glade accordingly
    builder = gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_from_file('yourprogram.glade')
    entry = builder.get_object('yourentry')

    numbify(entry)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am using text field to allow user specify number of hours or minute. I am looking at alternatives other than writing a validation for the user input. 

I will try to implement your suggestion and see how things goes.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to sanitize user input, avoid allowing text input entirely. If you're trying to collect hours and minutes, how about spin buttons or other widgets where you can limit the user's choice.

Check out the spinbutton example:
http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/spinbutton.py

Answer (score 0):

Convert your text to a number and in case it doesn't handle the error and set the text to an empty string.

You can generalize this to match a regular expression the way you want

```
try:
    val = float(entry.get_text())
    entry.set_text(str(val))
except ValueError:
    entry.set_text('')
```